# Fatal error: Base lambda function for closure not found in

Tags: php, magento, lambda

I am working on a **Magento - Enterprise Edition.**

I got the a fatal error:

> Base lambda function for closure not found in " in filters when i applied uasort function for filter attributes by based on product count to sort by product count

Code:

```
<?php 

$items = $this->getItems();

uasort($items, function($a,$b) {
    return ($a->getCount() - $b->getCount())* -1;
});

?>
```

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: Do you run a PHP cache like `APC`? Sometimes closures do have a caching bug as I read through the PHP bug tracker and some questions here on SO.

Comment: please turn testwise your apache ``apc`` cache off, this error ocurres often with write problems from the apc cache.

Comment: Do you have php 5.3.2 (or older)? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52144

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions not working in Magento as we expect. Here is the solution:
1) Add function to some helper, for example to your extension:

```
protected static function _compare($a, $b){
    return ($a->getCount() - $b->getCount())* -1;
}
```

2) Use next format:

```
uasort($items, array('Your_Extension_Helper_Data', '_compare'));
```

This will work, even with enabled APC cache.

Another variant: add _compare function to current file where you want to use uasort, in this case it will looks like:

```
uasort($items, array($this, '_compare'));
```

or

```
uasort($items, array('Name_Of_Your_Class', '_compare'));
```